# 2002 into 2001 ignition switch

Tags: ignition, ignition-key, ignition-switch, modification

Can I put a 2002 honda ignition switch into a 2001 honda civic? Would it work and fit? The original ignition switch is a little bigger and has more wires than that of the 2002.

Comment: Is the replacement switch also from a Civic? '01 and '02 cars are both 7th gen civics so I would have expected it to be the same. The fact that it's clearly *not* suggests it might not be from a donor civic. I can't see you being able to bodge a different switch in effectively.

Comment: If you check out all the functions of both switches then get the wires in the correct positions you might then be left with any physical differences.

Comment: Motosubatsu- yes, I'm having trouble with my 01 civic have to turn key really hard to start up. Looking to see if I can put an 02 civic ignition in.